# If $G$ is cyclic of order n, $\mathbb{Q}[G]\cong \oplus_{d|n}\mathbb{Q[\xi_d]}$

Tags: number-theory, abelian-groups, algebras

I am trying to find a proof of this result.

If $G$ is cyclic of order n, $\mathbb{Q}[G]\cong \oplus_{d|n}\mathbb{Q[\xi_d]}$.

I think the proof will involve the use of characters of finite abelian groups (which extend to homomorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}$-algebras between $\mathbb{Q}[G]$ and $\mathbb{Q}[\xi_m]$).

I am just looking for a good reference where I could find this result or useful information about characters of finite abelian groups which would help me prove this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can guess what all this means, but what are the $\xi_m$s? It looks like they are groups since you have written $\mathbb{Q}[\xi_m]$, where this is the group algebra. Is that right?

Comment: $\xi_m$ is (I think) a primitive $m$-th root of unity, where $m$ is the exponent of the group $G$.

Comment: Ok, so then what is $\mathbb{Q}[\xi_m]$?

Comment: I do not think I even know. I think it might be a set of (formal) linear combinations of powers of $\xi_m$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$. If you have seen something similar to this and tell me the reference that would already help because I am super lost here.

Comment: I believe that these are actually the cyclotomic field extensions found by adjoining the root of unity to $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G=C_n$ be a cyclic group, $g$ a generator. Let $f:\mathbb{Q}[x]\to \mathbb{Q}[G]$, $\sum a_kx^k\mapsto \sum a_kg^k$. This is a surjective ring homomorphism, and its kernel is the ideal $(x^n-1)$. So,

$$\mathbb{Q}[G]\cong \frac{\mathbb{Q}[x]}{(x^n-1)}$$

This polynomial factors over $\mathbb{Q}$ as

$$x^n-1=\prod_{d|n}\Phi_d(x)$$

where $\Phi_d(x)$ is the $d^{th}$ [cyclotomic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial). By the Chinese remainder theorem, these two facts imply

$$\mathbb{Q}[G]\cong \prod_{d|n}\frac{\mathbb{Q}[x]}{\Phi_d(x)}$$

and then finally, $\frac{\mathbb{Q}[x]}{\Phi_d(x)}=\mathbb{Q}[\xi_d]$ is the $d^{th}$ [cyclotomic field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_field) from the question.

Comment: If you like the answer, maybe you can accept it :)